# Connected webpart hide unhide

Tags: 2013, web-part

I am not looking here for readymade solutions but just need few pointers.
I have created 2 custom webparts. Added them on 2 seperate page. But i want to connect them or hide and unhide one of those depending on menu.

I would like to have breadcrumb on my page which will have 2 links. Selecting one of those will show one of webparts.

Do i need to create seperate webpart to show breadcrumb?
Not sure if i really need connected webpart. What will be best to resolve this?

Comment: Try to use Jquery...Or try to select check box in webpart properties to hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using Jquery. Just hide the web part which doesn't match the criteria. I could help you with the code but I need some sample code to work on.

**EDIT:** A sample Jquery to toggle between two items: https://jsfiddle.net/tupebw38/2/

You will have to use something similar

Comment: my code is too big. I have just 2 webparts placed in 2 different pages. There is no connection between these 2 webparts. I just need commong interface to be able to show these webparts depending on what is selected in breadcrumb or menu. Do i need to create seperate webpart for showing menu. Can you give me example on how to hide unhide webpart using jquery

Comment: Added the JS code :)

Comment: but where i write code for this breadcrumb. In seperate webpart?

Comment: Add it in an HTML file and include it using content editor web part